# Joining tables in a database using differently formated data (MAC addresses)

Tags: sql, mac-address

I have two tables that I'd like to join via the MAC Address field, but each table stores MAC addresses slightly different:

```
Table 1 data: 0:1e:8:c5:9e:fe
Table 2 data: 00:1e:08:c5:9e:fe
```

The first one removes starting 0's for ANY of the 6 groups of colon-separated fields.

Is there a way I can join on these in SQL without having to modify the data?

I'm guessing I would have to convert both values to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, then compare them...I'm just not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Any chance you could fix the source of the MAC addresses for Table 1?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  It's 3rd party data.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove leading zeroes with the `REPLACE` and `STUFF` functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ShortMac = STUFF(REPLACE(':' + Table2.LongMac, ':0', ':'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: This looks like it could work but how does it handle the first entry?  This looks like it only adds a 0 to the 1-5 entries.

Comment: @wfsaxton It works by prepending a colon to the first entry, and removing the colon afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to convert the values would be to split or tokenize the string on the :.  Then loop over the items and if size != 2, prepend a 0, and then concatenate them back together.  Kinda brute force, but it'd do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, they cannot be joined without modifying the data in some way.

I would avoid using the MAC addresses as primary keys since they can change.

If you must use them, is it possible to ensure they're all being inserted in a consistent format? Once that's taken care of, you could write a script (whether it's in SQL, or using another language in an application that can interface with the db) to update all of your existing records to a consistent format. You can just split them apart at a delimiter like the ':' and code to pad a 0 if needed. This would allow you to do your joins without having to create any sort of conversion methods.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a brute force approach like @plattitude describes but somewhat simpler you could use a regular expresion and REPLACE where each ':' character matches either ':' or ':0' and the shorter string or '0'+ the shorter string matches the longer.

Sorry in hotel room with no access to build and test expression but someone may like to add it to the answer.